# I am learning Drupal 7 and want to know the way to learn modules

Tags: 7

I am learning Drupal 7. I have read the docs about modules.

But still want to know the correct way to learn modules eg. how to use it, how to install extended modules etc.

Comment: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/faq **Requests for tutorials, and other online resources** are not allowed.

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers :) Unfortunately this kind if question is too broad to fit into our question/answer format and has to be closed. Once you have specific questions about your module development, please do ask them here

Comment: Apart from the great answer to this (closed) question, you may want to look at my answer at http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/164463/recommendations-to-get-started-with-drupal-and-grow/164475#164475 also ...

Answer (score 2):

I think the most important is experience. Just installing and enabling some modules, trying them out gives you a feeling of how things work. There are many youtube videos that show you exactly what to do. But I can't stress this too much: experience is what we need. Don't make the same mistake as I did in the beginning when I studied more than I tried.

Don't be afraid to try things out, even if they don't seem to work in the beginning. Be persistent and follow the guidelines out there. Should you need specific advice on a module, feel free to ask here or in drupal.org where you should become a member. (if you are not already!)

I don't think there is an "officially correct way to learn". If there is, then I bet it is called **persistence**! So get involved and see you out in the field :D.

Comment: thank you so much for valuable guidelines. I will learn the way you suggest me. and of course I have installed and enable some modules and working with it. trying to do things with the help of several tutorials and videos. thanks.